# How can I trigger the click of an HTML button on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to automate something.

I need to go a lot to a page, and click some buttons to download excel files (Communicatie > Exporteer ...).
I would like to just enter a link that directly executes the buttons. I don't know if this is possible.

[image: Screenshot 1]

When inspecting the source code, there is no link visible or something.
I already tried
https://mysite.be/page#communicatie_export_users_xlsx
But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Thanks in advance!
Laurent

Comment: You might also want to check out [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) for Firefox or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for Chrome. These can be set up to automatically run JavaScript on a given domain. Then you can run something similar to what mplungjan suggested.

Comment: if the file to be downloaded has a defined path, it can be downloaded simply via url, however if the file is dynamically generated, then check for form post/ajax request that generates the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function() { document.querySelector("#communicatie_export_users_xlsx").click()})()
```

create a bookmark and paste the above into it. Then you can just click the bookmark on the page.

An alternative is to first press F12, go to network and then click the button to see what the link is they actually call. That link can be automated if they allow it. You may run into violating their TOS

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer! The first option works fine, the network option not. I was wondering if it is possible to concatinate the javascript and the link in one? 
Something like this: mysite/com/page/javascript:(function() { document.querySelector("#communicatie_export_users_xlsx").click()})() 
Thanks!

Comment: That style of link is definitely not possible. If it was it would be a security nightmare as what you're doing is injecting arbitrary javascript into an arbitrary page.

Comment: Thanks. I tought it wasn't possible, but never new.
Thanks for helping out!

You might now how I can give a fileName to the file that is downloading?

Comment: You cannot automate that on the client. A server could CURL the document if the site allows it